# React log to UI instead of console

Tags: reactjs, mobile

I have an native mobile application that loads my react application within a child iframe (not sure exactly how it does it), but this application injects some variables into the page as windows.xxxx

So in order to test my application (yes, this sucks a lot) I need to run the app on my phone, have it open up the URL on my development machine (aka http://192.168.10.10:3300).

Then to debug anything I'm forced to alert(var1) .. as you can imagine this is a pretty painful process and I really wish the parent application would provide something better than this.

Normally a simple option would be something like console.log(var1) but I can't see the console on my mobile device and my URL is being loaded withing this native app.

So: 
1. Any suggestions on a better debug process would be welcome.
2. One idea that would help is if there was a react component that would simply
 print to screen anything any console.log().
3. I guess another option could be some kind of remote logger, so that console.remotelog(debugServerUrl, var1) pushes debug messages to the listener which then displays the debug.

All of this if a pain of course, but hoping someone out there has a clever idea for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using ReactJS, an easy quick-fix might be creating a log file in the phone. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656610/download-a-string-as-txt-file-in-react) details a quick and relatively easy way to save a string as a text file, and it would not be hard to put everything you want saved into a string.

Furthermore, [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673319/react-remote-console-logging) details an implementation of the remote logging feature you vaguely referenced.

Also, if you want to capture stdout and stderr, check out [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capture-console) npm package

Ultimately, hope this helps, and good luck